# Почему неверно срабатывает валидатор?

Tags: php, pdo, валидация, регистрация, формы

Есть страница регистрации:

```js
<?php
require_once("config.php");
if (!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
 header("location /index.php");
}
// обработка ошибок
$errors = [];
if (!empty($_POST)) {
 $validator = new Validator(new DB()); // Передаем валидатору объект базы данных
 foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
  $validator->checkEmpty($k, $v);
 }

 $validator->checkMaxLength('user_name', $_POST['user_name'], 'users', 'username'); 
 $validator->checkMaxLength('first_name', $_POST['first_name'], 'users', 'first_name');
 $validator->checkMaxLength('last_name', $_POST['last_name'], 'users', 'last_name');
 $validator->checkMinLength('password', $_POST['password'], 6);
 $validator->checkMatch('password', $_POST['password'], 'confirm_password', $_POST['confirm_password']);
 $errors = $validator->errors;
 // Добавлениею юзера в базу
 if (empty($errors)) {
  $user = new User();
  //Присваиваем свойствам объекта user значения из POST запроса 
  $user->userName= $_POST['user_name'];
  $user->email= $_POST['email'];
  $user->password= sha1($_POST['password'].SALT);
  $user->firstName= $_POST['first_name'];
  $user->lastName= $_POST['last_name'];
  $user->save(); // Сохраняем юзера в базу
  header("location: /login.php?registration=1");  
 }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Страница регистрации</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<form method="POST">
 <div style="color:red;">
  <?php foreach ($errors as $error) :?>
   <p><?php echo $error;?></p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>username</label>
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="user_name" required="" value="<?php echo (!empty($_POST['user_name']) ? $_POST['user_name'] : '');?>"/> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Email</label>
  <div>
   <input type="email" name="email" required="" value="<?php echo(!empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '');?>"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="first_name" required="" value="<?php echo(!empty($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '');?>"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="last_name" required="" value="<?php echo(!empty($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : '');?>"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>password</label>
  <div>
   <input type="password" name="password" required="" value=""/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Повторите пароль</label>
  <div>
   <input type="password" name="confirm_password" required="" value=""/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <hr/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться">
 </div>
</form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Класс валидатора :

```js
<?php
class Validator
{
 private $_db; 
 public $errors = [];

 public function __construct($db)
 {
  $this->_db = $db;
 }


 public function checkEmpty($name, $value)
 {
  $name = ucfirst(str_replace("_", " ", $name));
  if (empty ($value)) {
   return $this->errors[] = "Введите" . $name;
  } else {
   return 0;
  }
 }

 //Соответствие паролей
 public function checkMatch($name1, $value1, $name2, $value2)
 {
  $name1 = ucfirst(str_replace("_", " ", $name1));
  $name2 = ucfirst(str_replace("_", " ", $name2));
  if ($value1 !== $value2) {
   return $this->errors[] = "Your " . $name2. "is not match " . $name1;
  } else {
   return 0;
  }
 }
 
 //Возвращает максимальную длину поля
 public function checkMaxLength($name, $value, $table, $column) 
 {
  

  $name = ucfirst(str_replace("_", " ", $name));
  $maxLength = $this->_db->getMaxLength($table, $column);
  if (strlen($value) > $maxLength) {
   return $this->errors[] = $name . "is too long . Max length is " . $maxLength."characters";
  } else {
   return 0;
  }
 }
 // Возвращает минимально допустимое значение поля
 public function checkMinLength($name, $value, $minLength)
 {
  $name = ucfirst(str_replace("_"," ", $name ));
  if (strlen($value) < $minLength) {
   return $this->errors[] = $name. "Должно содержать не менее" . $minLength . "символов";
  } else {
   return 0;
  }
 }
}
```

```
введите сюда код
```

и подключение к БД

```js
<?
class DB
{
 protected $conn = null; //Конект к БД
 private $_host = HOST; 
 private $_dbname = DBNAME;
 private $_user = USER;
 private $_password = PASSWORD;
 private $_error;

 public function __construct()
 {
  $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->_host. ";dbname=" .$this->_dbname. ";charset=utf8";
  try {
   $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $this->_user, $this->_password);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
   $this->conn = null;
   $this->_error = $e->getMessage();
  }
 }

 public function getError()
 {
  return $this->_error;
 }

 // Получить максимальную длину любого поля
 public function getMaxLength($table, $column)
 {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('select COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
   from information_scema.columns
   where table_schema = DATABASE() AND 
   table_name = :table AND COLUMN_NAME = :column');
  $stmt->execute(array('table' => $table, 'column' => $column));
  $column = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
  return $column['CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH'];
 }
}
```

При сабмите формы регистрации валидатор выдает это: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Может кто-то подскажет причину неверной работы формы? Почему валидатор переназначает $name?***

**UPD1 :**

Если жестко задать  $maxLength = 100;
Тогда валидатор срабатывает верно, но я хотел чтобы информация о макс. и минимальной длине бралась именно из бд ( ниже сам запрос )

```js
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar (100) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `comment` text NOT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

В классе **`Validator`** переменная `$maxLength` не получает значение. Это видно из возвращаемого через `$this->errors[]` сообщения. Возможно такое, что **`CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`** в полученной строке  не было присвоено никакого значения (`= null`).

Comment: Так и есть, хочу понять почему. ( обновил описание)